# Get filename from HTTP POST file upload

Tags: php

I'm working on someone else's page that has a simple form with a file upload. When I do a:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

after the form submission I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [input_41] => Array
        (
            [name] => Resources.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpvVUox1
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 14563
        )

)
```

I now need to get the name of the uploaded file - I'm familiar with the POST syntax of retrieving form field input values such as:

```
$_POST['input_32']
```

but not sure how to get the file name within an array.

Comment: Just use `$_FILES['input_41']['name']` to get file name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in your **print_r()** output, you already have **name** property of the file in it, You can use this to get the name of the file.

```
$_FILES["input_41"]["name"]
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php